# Ref issue and Calling custom hook after useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a custom hook to detect outside clicks

```
const useClickOutside = (nodeElement, handler) => {

    function handleClickOutside(event) {
        if (nodeElement && !nodeElement.contains(event.target)) {
            handler();
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        return () =>  document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    }, []);  
}
```

And I am calling it like this

```
const Modal = ({ ... }) => {

    const modalRef = useRef(null);

    console.log(modalRef.current) // null

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(modalRef.current) // work fine here and display the dom element
    }, [])

    // here the hooks it is called with modalRef.current as null
    useClickOutside(modalRef.current, () => { 
        dispatch(hideModal());
    });

    return (
        <div className="pop-container">
            <div className="pop-dialog" ref={modalRef}>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem is that my custom hooks `useClickOutside` is called with `modalRef.current` as `null`

And as you see in the `useEffet` hook the `modalRef.current` value is correct

However i can't call my custom hook there in `useEffet` otherwise i will get `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component`

So how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing ref.current, if you just pass ref, your code will work since ref.current will be mutated at its reference when ref is assigned

```
const useClickOutside = (nodeElement, handler) => {

    function handleClickOutside(event) {
        if (nodeElement.current && !nodeElement.current.contains(event.target)) {
            handler();
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
        return () =>  document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    }, []);  
}
```

and in modal

```
const Modal = ({ ... }) => {

    const modalRef = useRef(null);

    // here the hooks it is called with modalRef.current as null
    useClickOutside(modalRef, () => { 
        dispatch(hideModal());
    });

    return (
        <div className="pop-container">
            <div className="pop-dialog" ref={modalRef}>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qkl0zyj1oj)**

Comment: To clarify, in the original version, `nodeElement === null` when `useClickOutside` is first called. The fact that `modalRef.current === div` later on doesn't change the value of `nodeElement`.